# when and how to use windbg kernel debugging

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I found Windbg is very useful during development and debugging.
but mostly i use windbg in use mode debugging.

1. What kernel debugging can do in windbg? 
   or When should I use windbg's kernel debugging?
2. Is there a toturial about kernel debugging in windbg?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you usually  use kernel debugging when you need to debug  low level device drivers interacting directly with the hardware.
   It's more complicated to debug in kernel mode, among other things for a live kernel debug session you  have to run the debugger on a different system than the one being debugged  .  for the majority of  developers user mode is enough to do most of the work.
[Advanced Windows Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321374460)  is a very good book about debugging with wndbg (includes discussions about kernel debugging).

the [dump analysis](http://www.dumpanalysis.org) site has many tutorials including kernel debugging scenarios

Comment: What if the application in question is run in a VM, and the host machine has the access to the symbol and source servers? There's a combination of kernel/user mode debugging (or rather, debugging user-mode application with a remote kernel debugger) use case there, isn't there?

Answer (score 9):

the main difference between user mode and kernel mode WINDBG, is you can see EVERY process in kernel mode WINDBG, and all threads. You wont necessary get to see every stack frame since they get paged out frequently by the memory manager.

some common commands I use frequently.

!process 0 0 
 lists every running process:

```
**** NT ACTIVE PROCESS DUMP ****
PROCESS 80a02a60  Cid: 0002    Peb: 00000000  ParentCid: 0000
    DirBase: 00006e05  ObjectTable: 80a03788  TableSize: 150.
    Image: System
PROCESS 80986f40  Cid: 0012    Peb: 7ffde000  ParentCid: 0002
    DirBase: 000bd605  ObjectTable: 8098fce8  TableSize:  38.
    Image: smss.exe
PROCESS 80958020  Cid: 001a    Peb: 7ffde000  ParentCid: 0012
    DirBase: 0008b205  ObjectTable: 809782a8  TableSize: 150.
    Image: csrss.exe
PROCESS 80955040  Cid: 0020    Peb: 7ffde000  ParentCid: 0012
    DirBase: 00112005  ObjectTable: 80955ce8  TableSize:  54.
    Image: winlogon.exe
PROCESS 8094fce0  Cid: 0026    Peb: 7ffde000  ParentCid: 0020
    DirBase: 00055005  ObjectTable: 80950cc8  TableSize: 222.
    Image: services.exe
PROCESS 8094c020  Cid: 0029    Peb: 7ffde000  ParentCid: 0020
    DirBase: 000c4605  ObjectTable: 80990fe8  TableSize: 110.
    Image: lsass.exe
PROCESS 809258e0  Cid: 0044    Peb: 7ffde000  ParentCid: 0026
    DirBase: 001e5405  ObjectTable: 80925c68  TableSize:  70.
    Image: SPOOLSS.EXE
```

.process {x} 
  Select the process you want to make active, usually followed by the !threads command to list a processes current threads.

!stacks 0x2 {foo.sys} 
 searches ALL threads for call stacks that contain the specified driver.

!poolused
useful when debugging low kernel memory situations and all you have is a kernel crash dump

.crash
Useful for when you are debugging live via serial cable and you want to make the target machine write a crash dump

!vm 1
Useful display of the memory managers statistics, example:

```
*** Virtual Memory Usage ***
      Physical Memory:     16270   (   65080 Kb)
      Page File: \??\E:\pagefile.sys
         Current:     98304Kb Free Space:     61044Kb
         Minimum:     98304Kb Maximum:       196608Kb
      Available Pages:      5543   (   22172 Kb)
      ResAvail Pages:       6759   (   27036 Kb)
      Locked IO Pages:       112   (     448 Kb)
      Free System PTEs:    45089   (  180356 Kb)
      Free NP PTEs:         5145   (   20580 Kb)
      Free Special NP:       336   (    1344 Kb)
      Modified Pages:        714   (    2856 Kb)
      NonPagedPool Usage:    877   (    3508 Kb)
      NonPagedPool Max:     6252   (   25008 Kb)
      PagedPool 0 Usage:     729   (    2916 Kb)
      PagedPool 1 Usage:     432   (    1728 Kb)
      PagedPool 2 Usage:     436   (    1744 Kb)
      PagedPool Usage:      1597   (    6388 Kb)
      PagedPool Maximum:   13312   (   53248 Kb)
      Shared Commit:        1097   (    4388 Kb)
      Special Pool:          229   (     916 Kb)
      Shared Process:       1956   (    7824 Kb)
      PagedPool Commit:     1597   (    6388 Kb)
      Driver Commit:         828   (    3312 Kb)
      Committed pages:     21949   (   87796 Kb)
      Commit limit:        36256   (  145024 Kb)
```

And don't forget the ALL MIGHTY !locks

absolutely essential for troubleshooting a deadlocked machine,

```
kd> !locks
**** DUMP OF ALL RESOURCE OBJECTS ****
KD: Scanning for held locks......

Resource @ 0x80e97620    Shared 4 owning threads
     Threads: ff688da0-01<*> ff687da0-01<*> ff686da0-01<*> ff685da0-01<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks.......................................................

Resource @ 0x80e23f38    Shared 1 owning threads
     Threads: 80ed0023-01<*> *** Actual Thread 80ed0020
KD: Scanning for held locks.

Resource @ 0x80d8b0b0    Shared 1 owning threads
     Threads: 80ed0023-01<*> *** Actual Thread 80ed0020
2263 total locks, 3 locks currently held
```

using this command you can track down threads that are stuck waiting for another thread to release an [ERESOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548046(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you'll only want to debug in kernel mode when your code is running in kernel mode, ie when you're writing a drivers or something else that runs in the kernel.  Or possibly if you're trying to learn more about Windows itself at a very low level by exploring around in the kernel and poking and prodding at things.

When looking for tutorials and other reference material, you might look for "kd" references as well as they are likely to be very similar.  (kd is a command line kernel debugging tool.)